# How do I draw this round rectangle?

Tags: java, android, xml-drawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZxAT.png)I am a beginer in Android doing an internship and i have been given the task to complete this navigation drawer for the app.Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please share your code and image of what you want to achieve

Comment: Image is already shared by me.What do i share in my code?

Comment: In your code you are supposed to share what you have done so far and where you are stuck. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new drawable and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/semi_transparent_white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```